# Laravel artisan migrate:refresh xammp give's weird error

Tags: php, mysql, windows, laravel-5, xampp

I used to work on a mac with laravel 5.3 / 5.4 no prob's with laravel whatsoever.

But since i'm back on my windows machine the problems start to come, i started with installing xammp, composer and then downloaded laravel. setted my DB settings in de .env file up and then I wanted to test the db connection with php artisan migrate:refresh which gave a error.

[image]

I did not change anything to the migration's so there shouldn't be any problem with it and since i'm kinda stuck HELP!

Comment: i see this . error is from sql . you must check database , this exist in table .

Comment: Yes but it's kinda strange because this is a fresh laravel installation.. And i never had this problem

Comment: you delet file and database . try again .

Comment: Yes i did, multiple times..

Comment: wow ! are you sure delet database ?

Comment: yes i did. never had this problem on my mac before

Answer (score 0):

Disable secure mode on **config/database.php**

Comment: I set strict from true to false but didnt make any difference

Comment: My future self does not condone this, please never do this if you know what you are doing.